# Add custom text to the end of .date

Tags: php, date, time, format, last-modified

I have a small section of code in my site showing when the index.php was last modified,
it looks like this:

```
<?php
    $filename = 'index.php';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "<p style=text-align:center'>$filename was last modified: " .date ("F d Y G:i P ",   filemtime($filename));
    }
php?>
```

It currently displays as, index.php was last modified: December 30 2013 12:36 +01:00

But where the +01:00 is at the end, I would like to add the text 'GMT' so user can know it's +1 GMT.

Struggling to work out how to get it in there without breaking the code.

Comment: Do you've even worked with php before? Or tried it yourself? It is kind of obvious ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<p style=text-align:center'>$filename was last modified: ".date ("F d Y G:i P ",   filemtime($filename))." GMT";
```

Comment: This works, but adds "Europe / Paris" to the end, where I'm trying to get "GMT" specifically :/ Thank you anyway!

Comment: so even if your timezone is different then also you want to show GMT?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 echo "<p style=text-align:center'>$filename was last modified: " .date ("F d Y G:i P ",   filemtime($filename)." GMT");
```

Comment: Hm, this doesn't work,  but it doesn't break either :S

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<p style=text-align:center'>$filename was last modified: " .date ("F d Y G:i P e ",   filemtime($filename));`

Comment: This works, but adds "Europe / Paris" to the end, where I'm trying to get "GMT" specifically :/ Thank you anyway!